# Scaling DA UpdateCursor to large datasets?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, file-geodatabase

I am currently having what appears to be a scaling issue with arcpy, da update cursors, and large file geodatabases.

I have a piece of code that iterates through every feature in a feature class and does some calculations and manipulation on the data. It works great for smaller data sets, but it is orders of magnitude slower on large ones. I have a simple counter in it and print statements every 1000 records for the purpose of benchmarking it and here are the results:

- 48k features, each 1000 takes ~0.12 seconds to do
- 133k features, each 1000 takes ~0.12 seconds to do
- 2mil features, each 1000 takes ~0.17 seconds to do
- 48mil features, each 1000 takes ~23 seconds to do (yes, twenty three seconds, no decimal place)

I only let the 48mil run for a few minutes before I killed it but the rest of them were ran until completion and these times are very consistent, be it the first or the last one with only a few hundredths of a second deviation once in a while. Even if they were scaling linearly I would only expect .05 seconds every 2mil records and that would put 48mil somewhere in the 1.3 second area. The results are 20 times that.

The ones with less features are just subsets of the data for testing purposes so it should not be an issue with differences in the data. All of them were created in the same methods, so I do not think there is an issue with differences in the data other than size. It seems to be coming purely from the number of features.

Sorry I don't have the exact code with me at the moment, it is at work, but this is basically it. The code itself works great though, I am mostly wondering if anyone as run into similar issues with large datasets. I was thinking that it could be a memory leak error, but these are all run outside of Arc in the python window and would expect that a memory leak would take time to ramp up (slow down) over time rather than instantly being much slower.

```
import arcpy
from datetime import datetime

...

i = 0
fromlast = datetime.now()
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            now = datetime.now()
            print i, ': ', now - fromlast
            fromlast = now
        ###do stuff here
        rows.updateRow(row)
        i += 1
```

I only have ArcGIS (ArcInfo license), gdal/ogr2ogr, and python to work with, but I am not set on using the FGDB or da cursors if there is some better way to do it within my limited selection of tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does creating an [index](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000011000000) seem to have any impact on run time?

Also, you can use a SQL statement to restrict the values you are accessing. If you really do need to access a very large amount of data, you can nest the SQL statement and cursor within a while loop.

Edit: I've run some benchmarks on my machine (Windows 7 x64, 2.4GHz i3-370m (lol), 8GB RAM, ArcMap 10.1 SP1). I created a feature class of 25,000,000** rows with a field, x, containing sequential integers. I'm assuming that update cursors are slower, so that is why I tested a search cursor.

```python
import arcpy, time    
shp = "C:/images/junk/massive.gdb/large"
entries = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(shp).getOutput(0))
test1 = []
startval = 0
breakval = 1000000   

c = time.clock()
while startval < entries:       
    sql = '"OBJECTID" BETWEEN {0} AND {1}'.format(startval+1, startval+breakval)
    test1.extend([row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, "x", sql)])
    startval+=breakval
print time.clock()-c

c = time.clock()
test2 = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, "x")]
print time.clock()-c

print test1 == test2
```

The results were as follows:

```python
614.128610407
601.801415697
True
```

This would place my read time at ~41,000 records/s or 1,000 records in ~24.4 µs.

**I ran test1 with 50,000,000 features and it took 1217. Couldn't run test2 as I received a memory overflow error. But regardless, I doubled the features and the time roughly doubled, which is encouraging.

I'm not sure the cutoff point for you where the access time skyrockets, but if this is something that you will be running often, it's worth the time to optimize `breakval`. To do that, increase/decrease `breakval` and just access a subset of your FC with SQL once (the entire FC clearly takes too long). If `total run time*entries/breakval` decreases between runs, then you can continue tweaking `breakval`.

Comment: I will try to do an index on some of the smaller sets of data, but not sure how that would speed up a cursor looping through all of them. I will also try a nested SQL statement, maybe 1mil FID at a time or something. Definitely worth a shot. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: I can only do so much testing on my end, as I'm running a laptop and creating a FC with even 2m records is taxing.

Comment: Thanks for doing any testing at all, its very appreciated. I don't even have Arc at home to play with so it is more than I can do at the moment.

Comment: ESRI's [ArcGIS for home use](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-home) is worth more than $100/year. I've learned quite a bit of scripting sitting on my bed, haha. Which is basically what I'm doing right now.

Comment: Definitely a cool idea there. Will play around a benchmark like that to figure out where the issue is. Also if I am reading that right the ones without a breakval is faster? Although it prevents the out of memory error from the 50mil features so that is good. Thanks for the idea and I will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Well it's only a 13 second difference, which is negligible when we are discussing multiple minutes of run time. It's also scalable up to very large data sets, which makes it ideal.

Comment: It seems there was some sort of issue with the machine that was running the code in question. It may not be a scaling issue with the DA cursor after all but thanks for the idea for scaling though. I will be playing with that too, might help a bit as well.

Comment: Even if it is slightly slower (2% for me) to break it up, I'll take that extra time if I don't get memory overflow errors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently trying to process some very large featureclasses with an update script, a simple search and replace on 5 fields in a dataset of 13 million rows.  My code was running terribly slow and reading this and geonet forum I came to the conclusion I needed to batch up my processing so my updatecursor makes uses of a whereclause and steps over 50,000 rows at a time. But this did not improve things, I then hit on the idea of removing the attribute indices that were on 3 of the 5 fields. Now that really did make a difference!

So my advice is if you are updating monster featureclasses remove the attribute indices!